# Using HashMap to count instances

Tags: java, hashmap, equals, hashcode

I have the following code to count the instances of different strings in an array;

```
String words[] = {"the","cat","in","the","hat"};
HashMap<String,Integer> wordCounts = new HashMap<String,Integer>(50,10);
for(String w : words) {
    Integer i = wordCounts.get(w);
    if(i == null) wordCounts.put(w, 1);
    else wordCounts.put(w, i + 1);
}
```

Is this a correct way of doing it? It seems a bit long-winded for a simple task. The `HashMap` result is useful to me because I will be indexing it by the string.

I am worried that the line

```
else wordCounts.put(w, i + 1);
```

could be inserting a second `key-value` pair due to the fact that

```
new Integer(i).equals(new Integer(i + 1));
```

would be false, so two `Integers` would end up under the same `String` key bucket, right? Or have I just over-thought myself into a corner?

Comment: Looks fine to me; that's how I would do it. Try it out ;)

Comment: @Vulcan I was about to, but thought my entire approach might be poor, so I thought I'd throw it on here.

Comment: Good code should use `Map<K, V>` Interface.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you are doing it correct way. HashMap replaces values if same key is provided.

From Java doc of [`HashMap#put`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put%28K,%20V%29)

> Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map. If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, **the old value is replaced.**

Comment: Thanks, major brainfail moment. I have been working with various `Collections` all week. **Of course** `values.equals()` is irrelevant, its all about the keys!

Answer (score 8):

Your code will *work* - but it would be simpler to use `HashMultiset` from [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com).

```
// Note: prefer the below over "String words[]"
String[] words = {"the","cat","in","the","hat"};
Multiset<String> set = HashMultiset.create(Arrays.asList(words));

// Write out the counts...
for (Multiset.Entry<String> entry : set.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getElement() + ": " + entry.getCount());
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, I shall look into it.

Comment: that's great thanks. About the array syntax: I feel I'm fighting a losing battle standing by that one :P

Comment: @lynks: Why on earth would you *want* to split the type information into two parts? The type of the variable is "array of strings" - if this is an old C or C++ habit, it's worth throwing away conventions which don't make sense in a new language.

Comment: I completely understand, in fact deep down I know I'm wrong. I think I just don't like seeing the [] in one place, and then in another when indexing the array. And yeah it's an old C habit.

Comment: @lynks: Well they're doing very different things - one is indexing *into* an array, and one is saying that the type you're interested in *is* an array. Personally I really dislike the fact that Java even allows the "split" syntax. Euch.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is perfectly fine. You map strings to integers. Nothing is duplicated.

Answer (score 2):

HashMap don't allow duplicate **keys**, so there is no way to have more than one SAME key-value pairs in your map.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine to me and there is no issue with it. Thanks to Java 8 features it can be simplified to:

```
String[] words = {"the","cat","in","the","hat"};
HashMap<String,Integer> wordCounts = new HashMap<String,Integer>(50,10);
for(String w : words) {
    wordCounts.merge(w, 1, Integer::sum);
}
```

the follwowing code

```
System.out.println("HASH MAP DUMP: " + wordCounts);
```

would print out.

```
HASH MAP DUMP: {cat=1, hat=1, in=1, the=2}
```

Comment: The lambda expression `(a, b) -> a + b` may be replaced with `Integer::sum`. So it becomes this: `wordCounts.merge(w, 1, Integer::sum)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a String-specific counter that should be genericized and have a sort by value option for toString(), but is an object-oriented wrapper to the problem, since I can't find anything similar:

```
package com.phogit.util;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

import java.lang.StringBuilder;

public class HashCount {

    private final Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    public void add(String s) {
        if (s == null) {
            return;
        }
        Integer i = map.get(s);
        if (i == null) {
            map.put(s, 1);
        } else {
            map.put(s, i+1);
        }
    }

    public int getCount(String s) {
        if (s == null) {
            return -1;
        }
        Integer i = map.get(s);
        if (i == null) {
            return -1;
        }
        return i;
    }

    public String toString() {
        if (map.size() == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        // sort by key for now
        Map<String, Integer> m = new TreeMap<String, Integer>(map);
        for (Map.Entry pair : m.entrySet()) {
            sb.append("\t")
              .append(pair.getKey())
              .append(": ")
              .append(pair.getValue())
              .append("\n");;
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public void clear() {
        map.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do all that when the OP wrote a piece of code that does the same thing in 4 lines?

Comment: Using objects allows for easier programming, in my experience.

Comment: Also demonstrating how to iterate in key order when looking at the result.