# How to obtain O(log(N)) complexity of the counting std::map of specific value

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am thinking about the problem of counting elements of specific values of map and how to achieve O(log(N)) complexity in C++. It is would be only possible when it is sorted by the values I guess, but then it would not be sorted by keys and the get from map would be then O(N).

In the first version I use `std::count_if`. Here is my code:

```
std::count_if( std::begin(_map), std::end(_map),
    [&val]( const std::pair<const std::string,  std::string> &p )
    {
        return p.second == val;
    } );
```

It has complexity the O(N). Do you know any other containers which would be useful for this problem? I was thinking about tree map but there might be a similar problem of sorting by keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boost's [`bimap`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html) allows lookup by either key or value.

```
auto range = map.right.equal_range(val);
std::distance(range.first, range.second);
```

Comment: Wow, that's looking really good, I think that is giving me te most capabilities so far

Answer (score 1):

You could maintain two maps so items would be indexed by by both key and value. You would need a [multimap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap) to allow for duplicate values.

Comment: I was considering this as well but it doubling the memory usage and it would be problem with big maps. I am thinking about this solution as a trade off

Answer (score 1):

Depending one your other typical uses of the container you can consider to use a `std::vector<std::pair<key_t,mapped_t>>` instead of the map. You have to do the sorting yourself, but you can sort for keys or values, and then do a binary search.

Comment: Thanks, how do you suggest to sort in order to meet time complexity limits?

Comment: @PPM sorting according to values is `O(N logN)` though you need to sort only once and can then use `O(log N)` binary search (`std::binary_search`)

Answer (score 0):

I've got an idea that it can be achieved by creating a [hash_map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13163547/using-hashmap-to-count-instances) hash function which increments bucket value by one if the value from map equals the bucket key. Then, it is only a matter of reading bucket values.

Comment: Add this to the description of the problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).